# Why is PyCharm giving the error "No such file or directory" when opening a Python project?

Tags: python, macos, vagrant, pycharm

When trying to run a project in PyCharm I get the following error.
I have setup the virtualbox, vagrant and all the requirements in the readme file they gave me but when pressing run...

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/usr/bin/python -u /Users/gtas/Projects/PythonProj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
bash: line 0: cd: /Users/gtas/Projects/PythonProj: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/gtas/Projects/PythonProj/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

**EDIT:**

It looks like the VM vagrant mappings are not properly configured/set.

I use a Mac OS X 10.9.2 and latest PyCharm IDE.

Comment: Are you sure that file or path exists(`/Users/gtas/Projects/PythonProj/manage.py')

Comment: Yeah, perfectly sure! I've checked it and it's where my project cloned in the disk. ~/Projects/PythonProj/manage.py. I cloned it from the Git repository!

Comment: Do you have the shebang at the top?

Comment: Try putting the shebang there `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Thank you for the hint, just resolved it. The mapping in the Vagrant was misleading and I put a folder down in the PyCharm mapping.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Started having the same issue after upgrading to PyCharm 3.4 - before that everything was working fine and after the update the same error. Also fixed by updating the path mappings: go to Run/Debug Configurations and manually define the Path mappings - Local path should be the path of your Django project and remote path the path to the project in the vagrant VM.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem and I solved it as follows

Fİle > Settings > project ["your project name"] > Python Interpretor >

Add Interpretor > System Interpretor > Apply

I try it and its working but you can chose local interpretor it can be work.

Comment: I run into this issue due to an update of PyCharm (PopOS) and had to recreate those interpreters / venvs. Thank you for that hint!

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by simply removing `.idea` folder. You can try also this way.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to add the project context root in the preferences.

```
Preferences -> Project Structure -> Add Context Root
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occur when u update the version of python and delete the old dir of python.

May be u can solve the problem by creating a new project with pycharm and copy all the files in a hiding dir named ".idea" in your new project dir to your old projects' "/.idea" dir，and choose replace.

Answer (score 1):

if your all setting is right, it may be the issue of pycharm version and you also get this problrm, you can do like this in of **Edit configuation** your running .py!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and what happened to me (I am a very new PyCharm user) is that my "working directory" was pointing to the wrong path where my file was located.  I fixed this by right clicking on my ".py" file and selecting "Edit Run Configuration:'pyfile" and adjusting my "working directory" to point to where my file was located.  Hope this works for anyone who runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem whenever I moved a project folder. I've found that the problem is the mapped folder in the virtual machine is no longer accessible; `ls` shows something like below:

`(vagrant) vagrant@ralph-dev:~/src$ ll
ls: cannot access ralph: No such file or directory
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Jan 11 07:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 vagrant vagrant 4096 Mar  7 09:45 ../
d?????????  ? ?       ?          ?            ? ralph/`

The solution is do a `vagrant reload`. After this the moved folder is mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that your setup involves virtual box and vagrant, you 
may need to update the path mappings in your Vagrantfile. In my case, adding synced paths between the host and vagrant like

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../code_folder", "/home/vagrant/code_folder"
```

then a `vagrant reload` and a Pycharm restart 
solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if you delete and subsequently recreate a file in your project where both files have the same name.  For example:

- create a file in the project named `foo.py`.
- run `foo.py` in PyCharm.
- delete the file `foo.py`
- create a new file named `foo.py`
- try to run the new `foo.py`